# Standard Deviation result wrong or right

Tags: standard-deviation

I made two scripts in PHP to calculate the standard deviation. But I am not sure if it works correctly both of my scripts have different results.

first script
1,2,3,4,5,1 = 1.5

second script
1,2,3,4,5,1 = 1.49

or are both wrong if so please tell me what the standard deviation is.
Thanks!

Comment: After the edit there is not really a discrepancy between the result, is it?

Comment: I edited just before you posted your answer, apologies for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average of your data is $$ \bar x = \frac{1+2+3+4+5+1}{6}=\frac83.$$
Thus
$$s_n^2=\frac1n\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2= \frac16\left(\frac{25}{9}+\frac49+\frac19+\frac{16}9+\frac{49}{9}+\frac{25}{9}\right)=\frac{20}{9}$$
and
$$s_{n-1}^2=\frac1{n-1}\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2=\frac 83.$$ 
This makes
$$s_n\approx 1.4907\qquad s_{n-1}\approx 1.63299 $$
It seems you are calculating $s_n$ and just use different rounding.

Comment: It seems that the second script works. Really appreciate your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With these few values, you can just run the calculation by hand.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=standard%20deviation&a=%2aC.standard%20deviation-_%2aCalculator.dflt-&f2=%7B1,2,3,4,5,1%7D&f=StandardDeviationCalculator.list_%7B1,2,3,4,5,1%7D&a=%2aFP.StandardDeviationCalculator.Form-_Pop) gives $\frac {2\sqrt 5}3 \approx 1.4907$

Comment: That's a nice shortcut. I asked this question because I don't know much about math only coding. The script I made was for a client that wanted the standard deviation for a score system. Before today I never even heard of it.